# How to fix unknown conda problem in terminal?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, terminal, conda

**Question:** I'm unsure how to remove this from my terminal every time it opens in VSCode. I originally tried to select the conda python interpreter in VSCode and think this is where the problem originated. I'm happy to remove the interpreter as I realised I actually don't need to use it and would like to revert my settings back to normal. Sorry for lack of question clarity, most of it goes over my head.

**VS-Code terminal display**

```
CommandNotFoundError: Your shell has not been properly configured to use 'conda activate'.
To initialize your shell, run

    $ conda init <SHELL_NAME>

Currently supported shells are:
  - bash
  - fish
  - tcsh
  - xonsh
  - zsh
  - powershell

See 'conda init --help' for more information and options.

IMPORTANT: You may need to close and restart your shell after running 'conda init'.
```

**Terminal display:** This is the message I receive after a brief pause when I open terminal normally on the Mac.

```
-bash: conda: command not found
```

Comment: As Mac comes with a bash shell by default, did you try running 'conda init bash'? I am not sure as I am exactly not clear about the question. But I would definitely recommend giving it a shot. Let me know how it goes.

Comment: Hi @VivekKhimani thanks for the reply, terminal returned 'no action taken'

Comment: Did you try restarting the terminal after trying out the command? The terminal snippet posted by you instructs to do so... After restarting try to check if conda is working....

Answer (score 0):

It seems that u don't have conda environments set-up.
try:

```
conda create -n --name NAMEOFYOURENV python=3.8.2(OR OTHER VERSION YOU PREFER)
```

You should be able to select then from VSCODE any evn you created. To list your conda
environments:

```
conda env list
```